# Replacing GLSL Conditionals with Math Beneficial?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

Being unsure of the sophistication of mobile GPU's but aware that in the past, conditional statements are expensive, I have been experimenting with replacing conditionals with mathematical equivalents.  I've read that the ALU's (and FPU's?) of modern GPU's can execute rounding and clamp "for free".  90% of the time that I need an if statement, I can harvest the equivalent result from a rounding function.  The trick is as follows:

```
// with an if statement
vec4 a_fac; 
vec4 b_fac;
if (a > b){
    result = a * a_fac;
}
else{
    result = b * b_fac;
}
```

Instead, perform the following math:

```
// equivalent math
a_greater = floor(0.5 + (a - b));
result = a_greater * a_fac + (1.0 - a_greater) * b_fac;
```

This is only viable when the magnitude of a and b are always in the unity range and the difference between a and b is always less than 0.5 (to avoid flooring to not in {1.0, 0.0}).  To prevent floor from going awry, I can use the following modification:

```
// equivalent math
a_greater = clamp(floor(0.5 + (a - b)), 0.0, 1.0);
result = a_greater * a_fac + (1.0 - a_greater) * b_fac;
```

Obviously this means many more FP calculations, so I'm not entirely sure if this technique is "worth it" or how to assemble a benchmark without texture-fill limiting.  The maximum shader instruction count might limit unless I create a loop, which is also expensive?

Comment: Wouldn't the `max(a,b)` built-in function do what you want to do with the **if** statement?

Comment: Updated.  The unique factors, a_fac and b_fac, are essentially what I'm selecting by making one of the products in the sum zero.

Comment: Nobody can realistically answer this question for you. It's going to depend on a number of factors, such as what math you're doing, what OS you're running, which driver, what GPU manufacturer, how you're calling OpenGL, and numerous other factors. The only way to know for sure is to profile your code with conditionals and without and see which is faster.

Comment: Totally agree with user1118321. My experience with shaders in iOS is that removing the conditionals usually improves performance, but different hardware and software setups and the actual operations that you use will make a lot of difference.

Comment: Seems round isn't supported in this version of GLSL anyway.  Saw the compiler warning on Desktop, says I need GLSL 140.  Needs more research.